# Springframework beans

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have not until now had worked with spring framework. I tried reading and reading the spring documentation but could not locate the answer to the following simple question.

The application is ant built to a build directory. So far when I tried to start the **JBOSS** (or apache) server, the logs says it is unable to build the bean because it could not find

> var/config/madagascar.prop.
>   .
>   WRT the following snippet in **WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="application.home" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperty"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>application.home</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="propertyFile" class="java.io.File">
    <constructor-arg ref="application.home"/>
    <constructor-arg value="var/config/madagascar.prop"/>
</bean>
```

Could you tell me where `{application.home}` and `var/config` are expected to be located?

Is it relative to the Eclipse project home or relative to WEB-INF?

What is the bean id="**application.home**" attempting to do - is it trying to read the value for "**application.home**" from the system env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"application.home" is the runtime value of `System.getProperty("application.home")` and the "propertyFile" bean is a java.io.File object returned from calling `new java.io.File(String, String)` with the whatever application.home is set to and that second String.

If the bean you wanted was 'propertyFile', the runtime equivalent would be:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("application.home"),"var/config/madagascar.prop");
```

That config is a very Spring 1.x (read old) way of doing things. XML is a very kludgy way to perform many of these types of initialization, and that's one of the reasons that Spring's `@JavaConfig` approach became so popular.